# angular2 : Cannot find name 'Validators'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular2 and the Visuel Studio Code give me this error : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5mFU.png)

This is my tsconfig.json :

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably because you did not import it...

Comment: try this " name :  new FormControl(null,[Validators.required]) " and also because you imported Validator not Validators

Comment: it's a typo.  you may close this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `Validator` to `Validators` in your import statement